# Weird behavious with component imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a component mapping that is used like this

```
import {InfoCard} from '@components/base';

const componentMap: ComponentMapping = {
  controlledTable: ControlledTable,
  infoCard: InfoCard,
};

...

const Component: React.ComponentClass = componentMap[data.class];
return <Component {...data.props} />;
```

The InfoCard is the default export of `@components/base/info_card.tsx` and is exported from `@components/base/index.tsx` like `export { default as InfoCard } from './info_card';`

This is so that I can import a bunch of 'base' components as:

```
import {InfoCard, BaseButton, BaseMap} from '@components/base';
```

The problem is that importing like

```
import {InfoCard} from '@components/base';
```

is failing for this one part of the code while working everywhere else. Also, switching to the following works

```
import InfoCard from '@components/base/info_card'
```

Can someone please tell me why this would occur...I'm not very well versed with how imports work in webpack.

**PS**: `@components/*` is a webpack alias I'm using for `ROOT_DIR/src/components`.

Comment: What you are importing with `import {InfoCard} from '@components/base';` is the type, not the component, component is a default export this is why `import InfoCard from ....` works cause this one is component import

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi But it works everywhere else...that is, if I import like this and then use the component directly somewhere like `<InfoCard />`, it works.